# Control audio playback in SSML audio tag

Tags: actions-on-google

I am playing mp3 file using SSML audio tag while in a third party app. However, I want to allow user to pause and resume the audio. Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

Keep in mind that the SSML `<audio>` tag on the Google Assistant is meant for short audio that enhances the text accompanying it, so it behaves more like text does coming from the Assistant. Unlike audio that is streamed, it isn't expected that people will need to interrupt it.

There is, currently, no supported way to stream audio through an Action.